# How to pass a parameter to Azure DevOps Build queue action created in Microsoft Power Automate?

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate

I have added my custom parameters to the build definition for a given project in Azure DevOps. I want to send values to these added parameters via Power Automate.

I added parameters and tried to pass these parameters in the action step of the workflow, but could not see the values coming in DevOps pipeline.

Here's the steps I have already:

1. Clicked on required Build Definition in the Build Pipelines
2. Clicked on EDIT
3. Clicked on the Variables tab
4. Added my custom variables to the build pipeline

Now I want to pass values to there custom variables or parameters externally specifically through Microsoft Work Flow using the QUEUE A BUILD ACTION.

Is this doable or can it only be used internally in the build pipeline, e.g. these variables cannot be accessed or values cannot be passed through external sources like Microsoft Power Automate?

If this is doable, can you please let us know how to pass the values to these variables externally and how to see them in the build pipeline that the values have been passed to these variables so that we can use it in the other steps of 
build pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point to note is: **the parameter should be in JSON format**

I don't know what parameters you've set, but I can successfully pass the parameter to the build pipeline through the following setting. You can refer to the following instructions:

[image: Queue a new build step]
[image: run duration and status]
[image: PowerShell script output]

Comment: Sorry if my query details were inadequate but i was not pointing about the parameters that you have explained. I have updated my query with detailed steps and description. Can you please look into the updated query details and let us know your inputs?

Comment: -Tried to pass parameters for custom variables also the same way you have explained and it worked thanks for all the help and time.Thanks a Lot